# creating threads using vector of pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

ok new try,

i changed my code from a normal `vector<Individual>` to `vector<shared_ptr<Individual>>`. since that, my threading code doesn't work and i don't have a clue on how to fix it. Start() is a void member of Individual, but how do i call it if there are only pointers to those?

```
std::vector<thread> threads;
for (int i=0;i<(Individuals.size()-howManyChampions-howManyMutations);i++) {
    threads.push_back(thread(&Individual::start,&Individuals.at(i)));
    if (threads.size() % 5 == 0) {
        for(auto& thread : threads){
            thread.join();
        }
        threads.clear();
    }
}
for(auto& thread : threads){
    thread.join();
}
```

it works when i change it back to just vector and the non-parallel version:

```
 for (int i=0;i<(int)Individuals.size();i++) {
    Individuals.at(i)->start();
}
```

works like a charm, too. So i assume there is something wrong at the thread push_back?
error messages (roughly translated) are:

```
 instance created from »_Res std::_Mem_fn<_Res (_Class::*)(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_Tp&, _ArgTypes ...) const [mit _Tp = std::shared_ptr<Individual>*, _Res = void, _Class = Individual, _ArgTypes = {}]«|
 instance created from »void std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::__call(std::tuple<_Args ...>&&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes ...>, typename std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::__enable_if_void<_Res>::type) [mit _Res = void, _Args = {}, int ..._Indexes = {0}, _Result = void, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (Individual::*)()>, _Bound_args = {std::shared_ptr<Individual>*}, typename std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::__enable_if_void<_Res>::type = int]«|
 instance created from »std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::result_type std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [mit _Args = {}, _Result = void, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (Individual::*)()>, _Bound_args = {std::shared_ptr<Individual>*}, std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::result_type = void]«|
 instance created from »void std::thread::_Impl<_Callable>::_M_run() [mit _Callable = std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (Individual::*)()>(std::shared_ptr<Individual>*)>]«|
 instanziiert von hier|
 Pointer to element type »void (Individual::)()« with Objecttype »std::shared_ptr<Individual>« incompatible
 Return-Command with value in »void« returning Function [-fpermissive]
```

thanks guys

Comment: Why the `pthreads` tag? Is `thread` something you wrote or is it the _standard thread_?

Comment: i thought that the c++11 threads are based on pthread. if that's not the case, sorry for that.

Comment: They are not, they are expected to work in systems where `pthreads` are not available. _Windows_ for instance...

Comment: okay, but please let us go back to the original question on how to create the threads from a vector of pointers

Comment: Does it work when you change it back?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
threads.push_back(thread(&Individual::start,Individuals.at(i).get()));
```

You can access the pointer hold by a `shared_ptr` with `get` method. However you should make sure that you do not dispose all instances of this `shared_ptr` before you join all threads or else they will have a dangling pointer of `Individual`.

Comment: quick test. seems to work like a charm. i have to store all individuals for about 20 generations. so every computation should be done by then. but, i'm curious if there is a more elegant method... for now thanks men :)

Comment: The clean way is to call the `start` method inside a lambda function instead of passing the object to the thread.

Comment: 'thread t([&](void){Individuals[i]->start();}); threads.push_back(std::move(t));`